# Python Ephem sunset and sunrise

Tags: python, pyephem

I am trying to calculate the exact amount of daylight hours for a given day and location. I have been looking at the python module "Ephem" for the sunrise and set calculation. Here is the code below:

```
import ephem
California_forest = ephem.Observer()
California_forest.date = '2001/01/01 00:00'
California_forest.pressure = 0
California_forest.horizon = '-0:34'
California_forest.lat, California_forest.lon = '38.89525', '-120.63275'
California_forest.altitude = 1280

print(California_forest.previous_rising(ephem.Sun()))
2000/12/31 15:21:06

print(California_forest.previous_rising(ephem.Sun()))
2001/1/1 00:50:46
```

The module works just fine like its tutorial showed. However, I thought you could save the "sunrise" and "sunset" output as a string. When I saved the calculation to a variable, it gives me a floating number that I dont understand:

```
sunrise = California_forest.previous_rising(ephem.Sun())
sunrise
36890.13965508334

sunset = California_forest.next_setting(ephem.Sun())
sunset
36890.53525430675
```

I was expecting a string that was the same as the print statement output, but I was mistaken. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can use these outputs and calculate the amount of daylight hours for a given location? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you get if you `print(repr(sunrise))`, what if you `print(sunrise)` and what if you `print(type(sunrise))`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is returning an `ephem._libastro.Date` object, which, when [convrted to `str`](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/master/extensions/_libastro.c#L502) returns the nicely formatted string you see when printing it.

If you just enter `sunrise` in the console, that actually does the same as `print(repr(sunrise))`, which does not produce the nice-looking string. It prints the underlying float value.

If you want to save the string representation, simply convert it to `str`:

```
sunrise = str(California_forest.previous_rising(ephem.Sun()))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really what is the string representation of your object. If you must get the string representation of it, then call the `__str__()` special method as follows.

```
sunrise = California_forest.previous_rising(ephem.Sun()).__str__()
sunrise
'2000/12/31 15:21:06'

sunset = California_forest.next_setting(ephem.Sun()).__str__()
sunset
'2001/1/1 00:50:46'
```

Comment: `__str__` is the *special* method called by python interpreter when converting something to `str`. It can be called directly, but it looks much better to simply call `str(whatever)`